# Insert and Select from another table in a MySQL Event (depending on date)

Tags: mysql, events, select, insert, dayofweek

For my time management system I'd like to add a new daily row into my table containing a value depending on the day of the week which is located in another table.
The values that I want to read are located in the colums s0 - s6 (for each day of the week).

Edit: Right now I'm at this point. New line is being added, but with "s2" instead of the value of that cell :(

```
INSERT INTO `table_write` (datum, soll)
SELECT CURRENT_DATE(), CONCAT('s',DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE())-1)
FROM `table_read` WHERE id = 51901
```

btw: The `-1` is just to get weekdays being shown 0-6 instead of 1-7. It works fine, it's just not letting me read from the table I want to read from :(]

I've never done anything with Events in MySQL, so I'm grateful for every answer.

Comment: What is the syntax error? (Include it in your question and not in the comments ;) )

Comment: No syntax error anymore - no result either ^^'  Edited my current attempt into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `INSERT` statement like below. Remove the `VALUES` clause all together cause you are using `INSERT .. SELECT` construct here.

```
INSERT INTO `table_to_write` (datum, soll)
SELECT NOW(), @soll 
FROM `table_to_read` 
WHERE id = 51901; //This where make no sense in this case though
```

(OR)

```
INSERT INTO `table_to_write` (datum, soll)
SELECT NOW(), CONCAT('s', DAYOFWEEK(now()))
FROM `table_to_read` 
WHERE id = 51901;
```

Comment: I've used this kind of structure already.
But the problem is: 
my variable @soll is supposed to contain the letter "s" and a number depending on the day of the week. ( as in my 1st line in the question. You completly ignored that part :D

Comment: @Nerevar, that wasn't clear in your post. See edit in answer if that helps.

Comment: thx for you answer yet again. It works to get the "sx" as a text, but he's not giving me the value of the field from the table that I want to read from. The only result I get is "s2" as value - not the value of `s2` FROM `table_to read` WHERE id = 51901 :/ It works perfectly when I just enter `s2` instead of the CONCAT ofc. Any ideas?

Comment: Edited my current attempt into my question above.